# Ktable Ktable join sample

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

```
KTable<key, Value1> table1
KTable<Key, Value2> table2
```

I am trying to join two `KTables` *(No windowing)* by key and write the result as `<Key,value1,value2>` to the output topic.

Could anybody help me to give some samples how to perform this operation.

Comment: How you want the result, which collection holds `<Key,value1,value2>`?

Answer (score 3):

Because in KTable you always can have just one key and one value, you need to use some helper class to join your Value1 with Value2. You can use `Pair<>` from javatuples library:

```
KTable<Key, Pair<Value1,Value2>> table3 = 
table1.join(table2, (value1, value2) -> new Pair<Value1,Value2>(value1,value2));
```

to write it to topic, you need to implement own serde for Pair value and then:

```
table3.to(keySerde,pairSerde,"outputTopic")
```

Comment: Thank you very much Stefan. appreciated your great help. will try with custom serdes.

Comment: If it was helpful, could you mark it as correct answer?